# Bixby: I'm looking for a way to make alert or notification by Bixby

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, bixby, bixbystudio

I am making a System which uses Bluetooth. But Bixby does not have Bluetooth API. So My plan was using Android Application and it catches notification then, send data by BlueTooth. But I recognize there is no Notification API in Bixby too.

So... Is there any idea to make a notification push by Bixby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is rather advanced. Here are some information that might help you.

1. Bixby is not allowed to edit contact or calendar other than using the already existing built-in capsule. Utterance example "add a meeting at 2 pm" would work fine already. There is **no** standard library for that.
2. If by "notification" you mean the pop up notification, there is a way to do so, but not directly from Bixby. The notification is an Android App notification that must sent by Android App. For example, let's call it MyEventApp and say you also have a MyCapsule. It is possible in MyCapsule using a deep link to request MyEventApp for a certain action (in this case, send notification or maybe schedule  one)
3. For how to use deep link in Bixby please read https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.app-launch as a starting point. There is also a github sample capsule.
4. The format for deep link (the payload-uri key in Bixby) depends on the MyEventApp and it's part of developer's responsibility to get the format correctly.
5. Please read carefully regarding https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/design-guides/design-principles.app-punch-out-policies Or your capsule submission might be rejected.